# Set notation not including first item in set

Tags: notation

I have a set $A$ (ex. $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$). I want to define a set $A'$ that doesn't include the first element (in sorted order, but all elements are inserted in sorted order and $A$ is always referenced in sorted order) of the set (ex. $A' = \{2,3,4,5\}$). Is there any shorthand that works for any set such that it will not include the first element (ie. also work for $B = \{20,30,40,50\}$ and $B' = \{30,40,50\}$)?

I understand sets are unordered, so I suppose the answer could convert the set to a sorted sequence and achieve the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you're trying to remove is always the smallest element of $A$, how about $A \setminus \{\min(A)\}$?